# Querying SDSS Magnitudes

Tags: python, astropy, temperature, magnitude, astroquery

I'm trying to retrieve b and v magnitudes for a specific star from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS) database, but I'm facing some challenges with my code.

Here are my requirements:

I need to input the name of the star.
Using the star's name, I want to query the SDSS database to get the b and v magnitudes.Ill use this in the Ballesteros formula to find the temperature of a star.
The code should handle cases where the star name might not be in the SDSS database.
I've tried using the astroquery package and the SDSS.query_region method, but I'm encountering issues, and the magnitudes are not being retrieved as expected.

Could you please help me with the correct code or suggest an alternative approach to obtain the required magnitudes from the SDSS database?

Im able to get the ra,dec magnitudes like this :             object_coord = SkyCoord.from_name(self.object_name)
is there a same way for obtaining u,v,r,i?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36868803/21350362